# Makefile: redefining variable in runtime using @if,eval: variable always takes value of last eval

Tags: makefile

So I'm trying to hack one of my makefiles to be simpler (simpler, as if, not defining a lot of rules how to transform subdirectory into .deb).

```
build-if-need-status-vars:
    @if [ ! -f debs/1.deb ]; then \
            $(eval STATUS_REBUILD=1) \
            echo "component: file not found: 1"; exit;\
        else \
            if [ $(shell find sources/ -newer debs/1.deb 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then \
                $(eval STATUS_REBUILD=1) echo "component: newer files exists: 1"; exit;\
            else \
                $(eval STATUS_REBUILD=0) echo "component: no newer files: 0"; \
            fi;\
    fi
    @echo "status $(STATUS_REBUILD)"


actual-target: build-if-need-status-vars
ifeq ($(STATUS_REBUILD), 1)
    @echo first status: 1
else
    @echo second status: 0
    @echo different action
endif

all: actual-target
.PHONY: actual-target
```

Test with:
`mkdir -p test/{sources,debs}; touch test/debs/1.deb; sleep 2; touch test/sources/1.src;`  (create makefile there and run)

---

Result:

> component: file not found: 1
>
> status 0
>
> second status: 0

---

Regardless of what conditional block is executed, `STATUS_REBUILD` will always be 0 (last evaluated value), try it: touch test/debs/1.deb

So it seems that last $(eval) is always used.. How to avoid this behaviour and keep the correct assigned value (from first match in build-if-need-status-var)?

Comment: `if [ $(shell find sources/ -newer debs/1.deb 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0` **cringe** You mean `if find sources -newer debs/1.deb | grep -q .`

Answer (score 2):

`$(eval)` is a make-level function. It is expanded in your recipe during recipe the recipe expansion stage.

The contents of a recipe are expanded in the second phase of makefile parsing (discussed briefly in the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles)).

I believe, but cannot say for sure (without testing), that recipes are not expanded until they are about to be run (but for the purposes here that doesn't change anything either way).

So your problem here is that *all* the `$(eval)` calls are expanded by the time make goes to run your shell script so you always see the last value in effect when the last line is run.

That all being said you don't actually *need* a make-level variable here. Your recipe is already only two shell executions.

You can simply include the last line in the same execution as the first (split) line and use a shell variable.

```
build-if-need-status-vars:
    @if [ ! -f debs/1.deb ]; then \
        STATUS_REBUILD=1; \
        echo "component: file not found"; \
    else \
        if [ $(shell find sources/ -newer debs/1.deb 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then \
            STATUS_REBUILD=1; echo "component: newer files exists"; \
        else \
            STATUS_REBUILD=0; echo "component: no newer files"; \
        fi;\
    fi; \
    echo "status $$STATUS_REBUILD"
```

Note that I needed to remove the `exit` pieces to make this work. If those are necessary in the real makefile (because this is a stripped down sample) then you can keep them by wrapping the `if` in a sub-shell and/or by rewriting the recipe.

Comment: I thought of using shell script.. but actually its a part of bigger makefile which has target do_something: build-if-need-status-vars (newline) ifeq ($(STATUS_REBUILD) command endif. So this will not work, right? :(

Comment: You are trying to set `STATUS_REBUILD` in a recipe for other parts of that same recipe to use? Then no, you can't do that for `ifeq` like that exactly. But I'd need to see a more representative example to say for sure.

Comment: I would just write the value into the `build-if-need-status-vars` variable and read it in the `actual-target` recipe. But if that isn't an option then I would split the two parts of `actual-target` into two different targets. Have them each depend on a different "stamp" file and just touch the correct stamp file in a separate target. (It might be possible to use a single target that produces multiple files for this but I'd have to test it to be sure.)

Comment: writing into `build-if-need-status-vars` variable is  that's what I'm trying to do with eval.

Comment: Sorry, brain-o. I meant "file" there. Use an actual file.